# Swift Tabbar with a rounded hole in the middle

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am trying to achieve the following design in my app:

[image: Tabbar]

As you can see, the tabbar has a raised center button. However, this is not the only thing as there should be a real hole in the tabbar so that it is transparent there.

How can I create such a hole inside a tabbar? And then put a raised, round button in that hole?

I would gladly appreciate any help regarding my question.

Comment: I also need to have same kind of feature for my application and I used https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar. It is good and easy to use library.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out. No hassle for you.
https://medium.com/@philipp307/draw-a-custom-ios-tabbar-shape-27d298a7f4fa

[image]

Comment: I tried that but he‘s using storyboards and I don’t - I‘m not able to apply all of the things he uses in the tutorial unfortunately.